# How to change text in text-field from inner-class??

Tags: java, jtextfield

I wanted to change text in a JTextField by using actionlistener on a button.
there is a radiobutton group and Sort.SWITCH changes its value according to radiobutton selected.

So when sort button is pressed the text in Output field must change from "Output" to "Some text"..
but the error is that Output field cannot be accessed from innerclass. Plz tell me the proper way to do that. thanks..

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 class Sort extends JFrame
 {
     ...
 }
 class q2 extends Sort
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
             ...
             JTextField Output = new JTextField(50);
             Output.setText("Output");
             ResultPanel.add(Output);
             SortButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
                 {
                       if (Sort.SWITCH == 1)
                       {
                          Output.setText("Some Text");
                       }
                       else if ...
                       ...
                 } });
            }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access your variable from inside the anonymous class, define the variable as a field (instead of a local variable), or as `final`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //...
    final JTextField Output = new JTextField(50);
```

Anonymous inner-classes may only access fields or `final` variables from the defining class.

Comment: The object is final - the reference to the JTextField may not be changed. However, it's member variables, such as the string in the object storing the text, may be changed. (This was written as a response to a previous comment someone wrote, which has now been deleted :( )

Answer (score 2):

Define `Output` as a class field:

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 class Sort extends JFrame
 {
     ...
 }
 class q2 extends Sort
 {
     public JTextField Output;
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
             ...
             Output = new JTextField(50);
             Output.setText("Output");
             ResultPanel.add(Output);
             SortButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
                 {
                       if (Sort.SWITCH == 1)
                       {
                          Output.setText("Some Text");
                       }
                       else if ...
                       ...
                 } });
     }
 }
```